Winit The content area size should be equal to window size
I have this code
use winit::{
    dpi::LogicalSize,
    event::*, 
    event_loop::EventLoop, 
    keyboard::{KeyCode, PhysicalKey}, 
    window::{Window, WindowBuilder}
};

fn window_setup(event_loop: &EventLoop<()>) -> Window {
    let window = WindowBuilder::new()
        .with_title("Motion Sketch")
        .with_decorations(false)
        .with_inner_size(LogicalSize::new(1280, 720))
        .build(&event_loop)
        .unwrap();

    let outer_size = window.outer_size();
    window.set_min_inner_size(Some(outer_size));
    window.set_max_inner_size(Some(outer_size));

    window
}

pub fn run() {
    env_logger::init();
    let event_loop = EventLoop::new().unwrap();
    let window = window_setup(&event_loop);
    
    println!("Inner size: {:?}", window.inner_size()); // Inner size: PhysicalSize { width: 1600, height: 900 }
    println!("Outer size: {:?}", window.outer_size()); // Outer size: PhysicalSize { width: 1600, height: 900 }


    let _ = event_loop.run(move |event, control_flow| match event {
        Event::WindowEvent {
            ref event,
            window_id,
        } if window_id == window.id() => match event {
            WindowEvent::CloseRequested
            | WindowEvent::KeyboardInput {
                event:
                    KeyEvent {
                        state: ElementState::Pressed,
                        physical_key: PhysicalKey::Code(KeyCode::Escape),
                        ..
                    },
                ..
            } => control_flow.exit(),
            _ => {}
        },
        _ => {}
    });
}

 


In function window_setup() I set the content area dimention to windows dimention, however the white area(content area) does not cover the whole window like i expected. What did I do wrong?
the image of window:
enter image description here

If you want the white content area to match the outer window size (ensuring it covers the entire window),
you should account for the window decorations. Since you're setting .with_decorations(false), decorations are already disabled, and your LogicalSize should directly define the full window dimensions.
.
fn window_setup(event_loop: &EventLoop<()>) -> Window {
let window = WindowBuilder::new()
    .with_title("Motion Sketch")
    .with_decorations(false)
    .with_inner_size(LogicalSize::new(1280, 720)) // Set inner size
    .build(&event_loop)
    .unwrap();

// Ensure the content area size remains fixed
let logical_inner_size = window.inner_size();
window.set_min_inner_size(Some(logical_inner_size));
window.set_max_inner_size(Some(logical_inner_size));

window

}
To ensure your content area aligns properly:
Use LogicalSize for consistent sizing across DPI scales.
Avoid using outer_size to set the inner size constraints.
